# Sileverlight change value from code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight

```
<Canvas x:Name="c1" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10">
</Canvas>
```

how do i change the value of `Canvas.Left="10"` from code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like the following:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(c1, 25);
```